# How to securely use an oauth token in front-end javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitch

What I'm trying to connect to the Twitch IRC via this library called tmi.js, which requires a Twitch username and oauth token to login.

I can do this without much issue, I just hard code:

```
identity: { username: newbot password: oauth:123123 }
```

With this I can connect to Twitch chat channels and do whatever I need to do. However, anyone can just inspect the page, look at the javascript here and take my bot's oauth token.

I tried looking up some ways to securely use this oauth token but got pretty overwhelmed with the results.

My question is, how can I implement a refreshing token mechanism, where the token changes after a certain time period and the javascript app keeps refreshing it? Is this even the recommended approach?

I need some help in understanding how Oauth tokens should be handled so I can come up with a good solution for this simple problem (probably without a simple solution).

Comment: As you say, anyone can read your JavaScript code at any point, making it **completely unsafe** to store tokens there. Store your tokens in the back-end. If you want to refresh it via JavaScript, you can use AJAX or XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Do you actually need to store it at all?  Presumably you could just retrieve it at runtime by calling the authentication endpoint.